# How to allocate memory for strings entered by a user in real time in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, realloc

I need to get an unknown amount of strings from the user (via keyboard) and set an array of string pointers so that it will point to all the strings entered.

I defined a variable `char tmp_strng[]` to hold the string the user enters using the following code:

```
printf("Enter string number %d\n",num_of_strngs+1);
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",tmp_strng);
```

After that I would like to allocate more memory to `char *str_arr[]` which is the array that will hold the pointers to all the strings. At first I do memory allocation with check:

```
if((tmp_str_arr[num_of_strngs]=realloc(str_arr,strlen(tmp_strng)))==NULL)
        {
            free(str_arr);
            printf("Error: couldn't allocate memory. Exiting.");
            return 1;
        }
str_arr[num_of_strngs]=tmp_str_arr[num_of_strngs];
str_arr[num_of_strngs++]=tmp_strng;
```

That does not really work... can anyone tell me what's wrong (or right) here? I would like to stick to realloc() and scanf() as the main functions here as much as possible.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior (though it may work in some implementations)

Comment: This is not enough code to understand your question. Please show us what is `num_of_strngs`, `str_arr` and `tmp_str_arr`.

Comment: You can't realloc an array. They are fixed to the sized they're declared.

Comment: `num_of_strngs` is an int variable that holds the number of strings in `str_arr[]` (length of array if you will). `str_arr` is defined as `char *str_arr[];` and `char *tmp_str_arr[];` is just a temp array that I'm using in case the allocation fails, if I won't use it and allocation fails I'll lose the entire array.

Comment: @TerraOrbis - Can I allocate memory to an array of size x and afterwards create a new array of size x+1 and use the pointer that pointed to the array of size x to point to array of size x+1?

Comment: Yeah just set the pointer to the new array

Answer (score 0):

Use the `getline()` function, it will automatically `malloc()` enough memory to hold the line. Usage is as follows:

```
char* line = NULL;    //Setting this to NULL is important!
size_t bufferSize;
size_t characterCount = getline(&line, &bufferSize, stdin);
if(characterCount == (size_t)-1) {
    //error handling
} else {
    //do something with this line
    free(line);
}
```

The `getline()` function is, just like `asprintf()` a part of the POSIX-2008 standard.

Comment: `getline` returns an `ssize_t`.  This is important as it can return -1 and your check for < 0 makes no sense on a `size_t`.